# Facing Dex 65K methods limitation error

Tags: android, android-multidex

I'm getting this error in my app:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]:
>   65536

I know that is due to 65K methods limitation in a single dex file. So, I have put `multiDexEnable true` in my `build.gradle`. But now, I get this another error:

> Execution failed for task
>   ':app:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForSitraRelease'.
>
> > java.io.IOException: Can't read [C:\Program Files\adt-bundle-windows\build-tools\20.0.0\multidex\shrinkedAndroid.jar]
> >     (No such file or directory)

What can I do?

**EDIT**

I have added `com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0` dependency and changed `App extends Application` to `App extends MultiDexApplication` and still not working.

Note: When I remove the dependency `com.batch.android:batch-sdk:1.5+` everything work properly.

Comment: What libraries/dependencies are you using?

Comment: You only set `multiDexEnable true`? You need to change your Application class, too.

Comment: @JörnBuitink What do you mean? Explain me, please

Comment: http://developer.android.com/intl/es/tools/building/multidex.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your build.gradle file, update buildToolsVersion to be 21.1.0 or higher. (You are currently using 20.0.0)

something like:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.0"
...
```

And also make certain your sdk manager is up to date.

More info : http://developer.android.com/intl/es/tools/building/multidex.html#mdex-gradle

Answer (score 0):

You have to extend your `Application` class from `MultidexApplication`.
Also, you need to add to your `gradle.build` file `compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'`.

Comment: @bigdestroyer maybe you should your update build tools? Looks like you are using 20.0.0 version, but 23.0.2 is latest one.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `compile "com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1"` to your dependencies in build.gradle. I believe you need this as well as `multiDexEnabled true`.